# Chakra Ui Modal - onOpen does not trigger until component state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I have been trying to solve this for the last 4 hours, I copied the modal code from chakra docs and the modal doesn't load when I click the losd modal button, it loads after I click any other ui element which changes component state ( forcing a render? ),

Im using react 18.2 and  "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.2.3",

My app is wrapped in chakra provider and I updated packages using ncu

Also I tried using useEffect and had no luck with that I tried using the component in App.tsx as well with no luck.

```
import { Button, Divider, Flex, Modal, ModalBody, ModalCloseButton, ModalContent, ModalFooter, ModalHeader, ModalOverlay, Text, useDisclosure } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export default function BuyerQrConfirm({ ...props }: any) {
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()
    return (
        <>
          <Button onClick={onOpen}>Open Modal</Button>
            <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} >
                <ModalOverlay />
                <ModalContent>
                    <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalCloseButton />
                    <ModalBody>

                    </ModalBody>

                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button colorScheme='blue' mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
                            Close
                        </Button>
                        <Button variant='ghost'>Secondary Action</Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </ModalContent>
            </Modal >
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: `modal doesn't load with inital click, it loads after I click a ui element` Can be more specific about this? You want the modal to be visible when user clicks `Open Modal` or should it be open in the initial load itself?

Comment: Okay so when I click the open modal button, nothing happens, the model only opens when any other component changes state.

Comment: [Its working perfectly for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-goodall-9g6f3f?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Hmm are you using strict mode in react?

Comment: it was wotking on codesandbox when ypu first shared but now it doesn't work there as well

Comment: yup. I added `StrictMode` in index.tsx due to which it stopped working. Check if you are also in the same.

Comment: god bless you man its finally working, and do you have any tips on getting back the strict mode without losing the modal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI I had the same issue as you. I am using NextJS and disabled react strict mode in the nextconfig file. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

The chakra developers already fixed this issue in the version 2.2.4, you should update the chakra packages to the last version, and after that, add the StrictMode again, here is the issue:

https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/6317